# C# Dice game, 2 dice, each dice rolls 50 times

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, console

I'm creating a 2 dice game rolling 100 times and giving the game statistics and it works, kind of.  The problem is that the both die's total is 50 when die 1 could be like 68 and die 2 could be 32 (Dice 1: 68, Dice 2: 32). How could I accomplish that according to my code?

```
int[] Dice1 = new int[7];
int[] Dice2 = new int[7];

Random x = new Random();
for (int throw = 1; throw <= 50; throw++)
{
    Dice1[x.Next(1, 7)]++;
    Dice2[x.Next(1, 7)]++;
}

Console.WriteLine("Side  |  times");//How many times sides 1-6 appear.

for (int side = 1; side < Dice1.Length; side++)
{
    Console.Write("  " + side + "        ");
    Console.WriteLine(Dice1[side] + Dice2[side]);
}

int total = Dice1.Sum() + Dice2.Sum();
Console.WriteLine("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
Console.WriteLine("total of 1. Dice: " + Dice1.Sum());
Console.WriteLine("total of 2. Dice: " + Dice2.Sum());
Console.WriteLine("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
Console.Write("Total Sum: ");
Console.WriteLine(total);
```

OUTPUT:

http://oi60.tinypic.com/140vzid.jpg

If anyone has any idea how i can get this to work please answer, greatly appreciated.

Comment: You want to be able to roll dice of various sides, not just 1-6? Is that correct? Your question is a little unclear. EDIT actually I don't think that's what you want. I don't really understand what your question is.

Comment: the dice is has 6 sides, 1-6, i want the first or the second dice to be able to go above or beneath 50 in total.

Comment: Please clarify the problem, it is very difficult to understand what isn't working from the question. Could you provide some sample data or "play" sequence perhaps? EDIT: How can you go above/below 50 in total with a 6 sided die???

Comment: im adding an image to the question in 1min, hold on

Comment: @Realitiez Still no idea what that means. You want to be able to change how many times the dice are rolled??

Comment: In your for-loop where you're incrementing variables in the dice arrays, it looks like you're just adding 1 to the total value of the array every iteration. This means that, no matter which int in the array was incremented, the totals for each array will always be 50 and thus the combined total will be 100.

Comment: Something for OP to think about (Under the assumption that both dice gets rolled at the same time) but why would Dice 1 have more rolls than Dice 2? If it's a two dice rolling game, doesn't both dice get rolled at the same time? therefore the number of rolls for each dice should always be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you're rolling 2 dice exactly 50 times (for a total of 100 die rolls).  It sounds like you want to perform 100 die rolls in which each roll choses a die at random to roll.  In this case, simply change your loop to loop 100 times, not 50, and instead of rolling both, choose one to roll:

```
for (int throw = 1; throw <= 100; throw++)
{
    if(x.Next(0,2) == 0)
        Dice1[x.Next(1, 7)]++;
    else
        Dice2[x.Next(1, 7)]++;
}
```

Comment: That's what i was looking for, thanks so much, i'm sorry if this was a bad question, been doing this all day, out of brainstorms =)